# Vue router order of routes from .getRoutes()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I'm using the following router configuration:

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'Home',
            component: HomeView,
        },
        {
            path: '/dev',
            name: 'Dev',
            component: DevView,
        },
        {
            path: '/dev/components',
            name: 'Components',
            component: ComponentsView,
        },
    ],
});
```

And when I try to access the router's routes using

```
router.getRoutes()
```

The routes are ordered like this:

```
DevComponents
Home
Dev
```

I would expect them to be ordered in the same order as how they were defined.
Am I doing something wrong or is there something I can do to have the routes ordered in the order they were defined in?
So like this:

```
Home
Dev
DevComponents
```

I think it has something to do with the route's path because if I change the DevComponent's path to '/components' it's ordered the way I want it to be.

**Update:**

The reason I want the routes to be ordered in this order is because I want to make a dynamic sidebar navigation component. This component will receive this array and then loop over every item and make navigation items in the order the routes were defined.

So this is my current result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the routes in the same order as you defined them in your router.js, you can use: `router.options.routes`. It gives you an array with the initial routes you declared. Then you can loop through this object to get the name and the path of each route.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. No idea how I overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

Vue routes are ranked and sorted by **score**, which is calculated based on the resulting regex of the route path. You can see these scores in [Vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) under the "Routes" tab

[image]

You can also check your route scores using this [tool](https://paths.esm.dev/?p=AAMeJSyAwR4UbFDACRAGvJPs742MAQHgANrl7RcgnQEAEg..), which is a tool you can find linked in the [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#debugging)

Besides changing the paths themselves, forcing `strict` or `sensitive` can affect the scores, but not in any way you can specifically control. These options will also change your navigation experience, which is perhaps something you don't want.

If you include your reasoning for *why* you expect and/or need `getRoutes()` to return all your routes in the same order they're defined, we can maybe figure out an alternative solution. Otherwise, this is just how vue-router works.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question and giving me more insight into vue-router, I understand it better now. I updated my question with more info like you asked.